# Access VBA: SUB designed to refresh an Excel Spreadsheet giving an error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Relative VBA newbie here.  I created a new Module **"QCDataRefresh"** with a Public Sub **"RefreshExcel"** that is designed to open an Excel spreadsheet (housed on my network drive) in the background and refresh it.  This is done in order to refresh the many data links contained within said spreadsheet.

Here is the code for this Sub:

```
Public Sub RefreshExcel()
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.workbooks.Open ("\\renssfile2\shares\Supply Chain Project Management\QCData.xlsx")
    appExcel.activeworkbook.refreshall
    Set appExcel = Nothing
End Function
```

Running this gives a run-time error '1004': "Application Defined or object-defined error.  Debugging seems to highlight the line of code "appExcel.activeworkbook.refreshall".  Not sure why though?

Additionally, I am also attempting to create a button in Access to run this from my dashboard.  To do this, I created a new button, and created a new Event Procedure for this entitled, "Command101_Click".

The following is the code for that Event, which attempts to run my RefreshExcel Sub upon clicking the button:

```
Private Sub Command101_Click()
    QCDataRefresh.RefreshExcel
End Sub
```

When I run this Event, I would expect it to give me the same error from my refresh Function above.  However, instead it opens a window asking me to select a Macro.  I'm unsure what my mistake is here, but I'm sure that it must be a simple oversight.  Thoughts on this as well?

Thanks all!

Comment: Why is your subroutine defined as "Private Sub Command101_Click(RefreshExcel)"  Perhaps take the "RefreshExcel" part out?  Also, a function should return something.  You should declare the procedure as a subroutine instead of a function as it isn't returning anything....Public Sub RefreshExcel().  Not sure if this will solve the problem though.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I went ahead and made both changes (edited the original to reflect them). Unfortunately, both issues seem to remain.  Thanks though.

Comment: Perhaps there isn't an activeworkbook.  Try to debug print activeworkbook.name and see if there is one.  Again, not sure, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the workbooks.open method returns a workbook.

Try this:

```
Public Sub RefreshExcel()
Dim appExcel As Object
Dim excelwb As Excel.Workbook
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excelwb = appExcel.workbooks.Open ("\\renssfile2\shares\Supply Chain Project Management\QCData.xlsx")
excelwb.refreshall
Set excelwb = Nothing
Set appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  It would seem that Excel.Workbook is not a defined method or type.  I feel like we're getting closer though.

Comment: Ok update: I added the Excel Library in Tools -> References.  It now recognizes Excel.Workbook, but still balks at excelWB.refreshall.  A quick google search indicates that many people use this... why does it not seem to recognize this keyword for me?

Comment: Is the workbook protected?  Or already open (so it's being opened readonly)?

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I have unexpected and unusual issue\error for using excel to output to or read from I allways try the following, especially when the code breaks in the middle and doesn't get to the line where you close the spreadsheet and close the Excel object from memory.

So close your spreadsheet and any Excel instances and objects you may have as follow:

1. Close all Excel files and excel program if you have any open
2. Go to the Task Manager (by doing Alt+Ctrl+Del) then select Task Manager
3. Go to processes tab
4. Sort by process name
5. Look for any Excel.exe in the list and force close them all one by one

Let us know.

Comment: This is not an answer